# Change color of footer border

Tags: html, css

```
<footer>
<center>
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()" style= "padding-right:30px;color: blue;font-size:20px;">*How it works
  <span class="popuptext" id="myPopup">how it works</span>
</div>
<a href="#" style= "padding-right:30px;color: blue;margin-top:100px;font-size:20px;">* Site Owners</a>
</center>   
</footer>
```

My CSS:

```
footer {
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    border-top: solid rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-shadow: 3px 4px 5 px 6px #000;
}
```

I put a border top on my footer, but I want it to be the same color as my background photo so it would look like a bump. My background photo is a gradient image. Any ideas? Box shadow didnt work, I tried doing `color: inherit` but it didnt work.

Comment: please change in box-shadow: 3px 4px 5px 6px #000;.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got a space in the wrong place in your `box-shadow`, it should be:

```
box-shadow: 3px 4px 5px 6px #000;
```

Comment: Is there a way to remove the #000 because I kinda get a black border

Comment: What do you want to get?

Comment: I just want a border to that has no color that would match with my image, its like its transparent, and gets the color of my background image

Comment: You can't detect the color an image using css if that's what you are looking for, outherwise I don't understand what you want to achive.

Comment: It worked, I just didn't remove border-top, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use z-index to do the same thing.
[This link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp)

Comment: It just made it display a normal border.

Comment: You must use z-index and box-shadow at the moment.